# Fixed ip to specific lan port

Tags: cisco, dedicated-server

How should I go forth to set a fixed/static ip dedicated to one lan port in my switch or router, so that everything i plug in that specific port acquires the same ip?

I have a Linksys EA6700 Wireless router and a Cisco SB 300 24x Switch.
I've looked through the management web interfaces on both of them, without discovering any obvious solutions. Would I have to set up a very constrict vlan maby?

Comment: You'll have to work some dark magic to do that with VLANs and DHCP ranges, since you're trying to accomplish something that seems to go against the intent of multi-port switches in the first place. Generally, you allocate an IP to a given device, and you don't care so much about what port it's plugged in to, not vice-versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to accomplish sounds more like the - depending on your environment - something that can be accomplished with DHCP reservations. As John mentioned above, there is "dark magic" if you were to go the VLAN route, as in, set the individual port to a specific VLAN and then narrow the DHCP range on that VLAN to a single IP address. (Please don't do that ever- I can think of no reason to ever do that, ever)

Comment: I can see how the vlan route would not be a great solution:) My object with this setup is mainly to save some time; we have quite a high flow of linux computers through my office, who needs fixing of some sort. After plugin them into the ethernet, I usually go to the routers webinterface to locate the ip before ssh'ing in. If I could just have one dedicated ethernet cable I plugged them into, and ssh'd to the same ip all the time, it would save me all the 'searching' =)

Comment: I see, you're basically just plugging them into a power outlet and an Ethernet cable huh? May I, then, humbly suggest a simple workbench with a dedicated monitor, mouse, keyboard on a KVM?